# Как в Android закрыть все Активити?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть 4 Активити. Если нажать на стрелку то будет переход с 4 - 3 - 2 - 1.

Мне надо еще добавить функцию в свою программу так чтобы при нажатии на красный круг, был не просто переход на 1 активити, а Нужно закрыть 4 3 и 2 активти.

Это мне нужно чтобы не было утечки памяти и тормозов, помогите

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Используйте флаг:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FourActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

он закроет все активности, которые "выше" вызванной

Comment: Удаляет активити которые выше FirstActivity? Тоесть 2 3 4 удаляит?

Comment: да. Если вызвать, например, активность 2, то закроются только 3 и 4