# Как закрыть приложение в Android

Tags: android

У меня приложение выполняется в главном активити `MainActivity` а мне нужно, чтобы приложение закрывалось через пункт меню настроек. Я пробовал вот так вызывать в классе `settings extends PreferenceActivity` но ничего не происходит:

```
    Preference pfinish = (Preference)findPreference(getString(R.string.settings_finish));
    pfinish.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            MainActivity mp = new MainActivity();
            mp.finish();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Вообще, во многих пограммах есть пункт `Exit` как это сделать?

Comment: активити - системный компонент, который создает, соответственно только система, создание его экземпляра через `new` - это не создание активити и он не имеет никаких свойств реальной активити, в том числе и не закрывает ее

Comment: @AseN не надо советовать для андроида `System.exit(0)`

Comment: проверил, при вызове System.exit(0) - закрывается окно настроек и я попадаю в MainActivity

Comment: @pavel, особенности, о которых, по-видимому, вы ведете речь, касаются версий 7 и выше. Но согласен с тем, что это далеко не лучший способ закрытия.

Comment: @Hellraiser мне лично ответ с `killProcess` кажется подходящим.

Comment: killProcess не срабатывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это единственное открытое activity в приложении, то можно использовать просто:

```
finish();
```

без обращения к какому-либо экземляру.
Чтобы закрыть приложение с любым количеством activity есть:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Но вам скорее всего подойдет и `finish()`

Comment: Список настроек вызывается во втором активити, поэтому finish() не помагает. А вот вызов killProcess - вылетает Тост "Unfortunately приложение has stoped" и я опять в MainActivity

Answer (score 2):

Класс активности не является синглтоном, судя по вашим ощущениям, прослеживающимся в коде. Создание активности было порождено интентом => класс активности уже был создан за вас кем-то (системой, ActivityManager`ом).

Закрыть конкретную активность можно, обладая ее экземпляром.

Способы закрытия приложения как совокупности активностей:

- `finishAffinity()`      - экземпляр нужен
- `finishAndRemoveTask()` - экземпляр нужен
- `System.exit(0)`        - экземпляр не нужен (в стеке должно быть не более 1 активности)

Answer (score 0):

На кнопку в настройках вешаешь листенер и в нём прописываешь

```
finish();
```

Comment: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501721/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-android-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%90%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8?rq=1) ещё это посмотрите

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/227378)

Comment: Понятно. Но времени особо не было.